# autocomplete text in searchview using string array

Tags: android

I am new to the android app developement. I searched many post but I didn't get any stright answer for my requirement.

I want to add autocomplete functionality to searchview. I want multiple string array to be listed in the autocomplete text.

my menu/main.xml is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

my string.xml is

```
<string-array name="countries_list">
    <item>India</item>
    <item>US</item>
    <item>UK</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="states_list_in">
    <item>AndhraPradesh</item>
    <item>Karnataka</item>
    <item>UP</item>
</string-array>
```

my main activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
  {

          private SearchView mSearchView;
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
          {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          }
          public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
          {
              getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
              MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); 
              mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView(); 
              setupsearchview(mSearchView);
          }
          setupsearchview(SearchView SearchView)
          {
           ////////////////////////////
          }
}
```

what should be added in the setupsearchview() function to auto list the countries_list and states_list_in in searchview.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. http://innovativenetsolutions.com/2013/07/android-tutorial-search-interface-search-dialog/ this link conatins the example code with sql database